# Ranking a list in python with None values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to find the rank of list items in an efficient way. The problem is when I have a None value.

My current solution put the None either at the top or bottom of the rank depending on the `reverse` value:

```py
tmp = [29.84087, 34.3745, 34.91104, 35.72471, 19.31632, 728.1475, None, 404.3762, None]

[sorted(values, key=lambda x: (x is None, x), reverse=False).index(x) + 1 for x in values]

-> [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 8, 6]
```

How should I change the ranking code to get None for None values?

Desired output looks like this:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, None, 6, None]
```

Comment: Do you want the `None` values to be in the result, or to remove them?

Comment: I want  them to be in the result as None.

Comment: is this your expected result? `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, None, 6]`

Comment: What's your expectations, bacouse it's not clear for me?

Comment: You should save a lot computation by not creating a sorted list for every item in the values list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions) in the list comprehension to keep None values as None.

And by doing the sorting operation once for all, before the list comprehension, we avoid a lot of unnecessary computation.

```
values = [29.84087, 34.3745, 34.91104, 35.72471, 19.31632, 728.1475, None, 404.3762]
sorted_v = sorted(x for x in values if x is not None)
ranks = [None if x is None else sorted_v.index(x) + 1 for x in values]
# [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, None, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, is there any workaround to make it a one liner?

Comment: @MehdiZare Replace the newline with a semicolon

Comment: :) I meant one operation

Comment: @MehdiZare I can't find a way without sorting the list on every iteration.

Comment: @MehdiZare Can I ask why it's important to have only one operation. Can't you create a function for it

Comment: It's just my preference, you're right. It can be converted to a function easily.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
import numpy as np
tmp =  [29.84087, 34.3745, 34.91104, 35.72471, 19.31632, 728.1475, None, 404.3762, None]
tmp_np = np.array(tmp, dtype=np.float)

mask = ~np.isnan(tmp_np)

rank_maksed = np.empty_like(tmp_np[mask])
np.put_along_axis(rank_maksed, 
                  np.argsort(tmp_np[mask]),
                  np.arange(np.sum(mask))+1,
                  axis=0)
rank = np.full_like(tmp_np, np.nan)
rank[mask] = rank_maksed
print(rank)
# --> array([ 2.  3.  4.  5.  1.  7. nan  6. nan])
```

Note: Updated after @pakpe's comment

Comment: This returns nan at the wrong index.  It's supposed to be at index 6, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

Mehdi, the following list comprehension removes None from your list, sorts the list, and returns a list of ranks. On the second line, you insert the rank of None back into the rank list.

```
ranks = [sorted([item for item in tmp if item]).index(item) + 1 for item in tmp if item]
ranks.insert(tmp.index(None), None)


#print(ranks) >> [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, None, 6]
```

Comment: This does not work if there are more than one `None` in `tmp`.

Comment: @Jolbas We are assuming that each entry in the list is unique, otherwise ranking them would be meaningless. So None presumably occurs only once as does any other value.

Comment: Could there be a `tie` if some items are equal values?  Then the `set` can help in that situation.  Just $.02     (ranking sill possible then)

Comment: @DanielHao I don’t think the question includes tue scenarios because the author’s own solution (and all of ours) are indexed-based and wouldn’t work for ties.

Comment: Sure. I understood that.  Just try to echo the earlier post/comments from others. NP.

Comment: Why do you say that if there are ties, ranking would be meaningless and the OP's solution wouldn't work? Isn't it simply the [Standard competition ranking ("1224" ranking)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking)) then?

Comment: It also raises a `ValueError` when the list does not contain any `None`

Comment: Thank you @pakpe! I should have mentioned that there may be more than one None, but the possibility of duplicate value is infinitesimal. The ideal solution would return a tie in the event of duplicate values, but None for None values.